# Add new item template parameter in Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: visual-studio, templates, parameters

I would like to create new add-in for Visual Studio 2012 which adds new parameter for item templates. The idea is to use the new parameter in class, interface and other existing templates.
The problem is the new parameter is not static. I need to query LDAP and WMI.
Does anybody know how to do that?